# ¿Es posible cambiar el color de fondo de la barra que está encima de la barra de tareas?

Tags: android

Yo he podido cambiar el color de fondo de la barra de tareas que está en mi App.

La idea es cambiar dicho color de forma dinámica, según el valor de la variable `colorTiempo`, como se puede ver en este código:

```
 private void setBarColor(int colorTiempo) {

        switch (colorTiempo) {
            case 1:
                getSupportActionBar()
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_adviento)));
                break;
            case 2:
                getSupportActionBar()
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_navidad)));
                break;
            case 3:
                getSupportActionBar()
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_cuaresma)));
                break;
            case 6:
                getSupportActionBar()
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_blanco)));
                break;
            case 92:
                getSupportActionBar()
                        .setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_toolbar_santos_rojo)));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }


}
```

Este es un ejemplo:

La toolbar está en amarillo, pero cambiaría a otro color si el valor de `colorTiempo` fuese otro. Eso funciona perfectamente con respecto a la toolbar.

Pero en la parte superior, donde está la hora, está en azul.

- ¿**Podría cambiar la parte azul** a otro color personalizado mediante código, como hago con la toolbar?
- ¿**A qué método tendría que recurrir** para setear el color de esa barra?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Acabo de ver que deseas realizarlo también dinamicamente.

Comment: @Elenasys sí, querría hacerlo de forma dinámica, no me expliqué bien en la primera redacción de la pregunta.

Comment: Desde API 21 puedes usar getWindow().setStatusBarColor() ya lo agregué a la respuesta. @A.Cedano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma de cambiar la barra de estatus se puede realizar modificando el color `colorPrimary` que asigna a tu tema:

```
 <color name="colorPrimary">...</color>
```

Como ejemplo tengo una aplicación a la cual quiero cambiar el color de la barra de estatus a color verde, modifico este color dentro de `colors.xml`:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#43A047</color>
```

---

Dinamicamente lo puedes realizar de esta forma desde API 21, definiendo claro el color deseado dentro de `colors.xml`:

```
 getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.StatusbarColor));
```

Para tener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sí Jorge ha funcionado. Opto por tu respuesta por dar más posibilidades de compatibilidad, aunque la respuesta de @GustavoMora también funciona. Gracias a los dos.

Comment: Excelente, gracias, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Hola la puedes cambiar de manera dinámica con el siguiente código:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Funcionara siempre y cuando sea Android version Lollipop o superior.
Te dejo la referencia de donde lo he encontrado en el sitio en Inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26749343

Saludos!

Comment: Funciona correctamente Gustavo, pero la propuesta de Jorge da una mayor amplitud de compatibilidad. De todos modos muchas gracias.

Comment: Claro con gusto @A.Cedano. Si me permites un aporte adicional, puedes programar themes en el recurso styles.xml. Esto lo puedes cambiar de manera dinámica en código y lo llamativo de esto es que puedes cambiar no solo de la barra de estado sino también de todos los componentes que uses siempre y cuando uses los mismos recursos de color por ejemplo ...color=?android:colorPrimary

Comment: Interesante Gustavo. Sería una forma interesante. Lo tendré en cuenta para futuras evoluciones del código. Gracias de nuevo.